# List s3 files by newest

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I am working on a Lambda that needs to list the objects in an S3 bucket and build a URL based on the files *item.Key. The problem I am fast approaching is that soon the bucket will contain more than 1000 items.

Currently, I am using a `for` to only return the last file that contains a specific item.Key:

```
resp, err := s3Client.ListObjects(&s3.ListObjectsInput{Bucket: aws.String(bucket)})
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Unable to list items in bucket %q, %v", bucket, err)
}

for _, item := range resp.Contents {
    if strings.Contains(*item.Key, "/output.txt") {
        lastItem = *item
    }
}
s := fmt.Sprintf("https://s3.%s.amazonaws.com/%s/%s", region, bucket, *lastItem.Key)
fmt.Println(s)
```

My understanding is that once the bucket reaches over 1000 items the 1000th item will be returned each time the Lambda is run.

By default bucket items are returned by oldest first, the best way I can see around this is to list the items by newest first and have the `for` stop after the first item. Is this possible?

If not, has anyone else solved a similar issue?

Comment: You want to retrieve the newest object from a bucket in Go?

Comment: S3 bucket list results are always returned in UTF-8 binary order. Each list call will return up to 1000 keys, and an indication if more are available (so that you can call the API again to get the next 1000 results).